# Buscar un nombre exacto en un archivo de texto con Bash

Tags: archivo, bash, shell-script, grep

Estoy escribiendo un Script en el cual una de las funciones es buscar en un archivo de texto DNI o Nombre que se piden al usuario y cuando las encuentre imprimir las líneas enteras.

El archivo tiene el formato "DNI | Nombre"

```
  2:Pepe
 21:Julio
  1:Marta
```

La función `buscarNombre` me funciona correctamente:

```
function buscarNombre()
{

    echo Introduce Nombre a buscar:
    read nombrex

    nombrex=`grep "\$nombre\b" agenda.txt`
    echo $nombrex
    menu
}
```

Pero la funcion buscarDNI en vez de buscar e imprimir  un DNI en concreto me buscar e imprime cualquier DNI que contenga el número que les he pasado.

```
function buscarDNI()
{

    echo Introduce DNIx a buscar:
    read DNIx

    DNIx=`grep "\$DNIx\b" agenda.txt`
    echo $DNIx
    menu
}
```

Si por ejemplo, le digo que busque el DNI:2 , me va a imprimir las lineas 2:Pepe y 21:Julito y solo quiero que me imprima 2:Pepe.

¿Cómo puedo mejorar `buscarDNI` para que solo busque el DNI exacto?

Comment: ¿Seguro que te devuelve distintos valores si le das "2"? A mí me devuelve solamente "2:Pepe". Dicho lo cual, una entrada "12:Juanito" también encajaría.

Comment: el formato del archivo es correcto? lo digo porque tienes un espacio al principio de la primera y la tercera linea, y no tienes espacio en la segunda... acaso tus "dnis" van a tener solo 2 caracteres? lo digo para buscar una expresion regular mas acorde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa `grep -w` , el cual busca la palabra exacta

```
function buscarDNI()
{

    echo Introduce DNIx a buscar:
    read DNIx

    DNIx=`grep -w "\$DNIx\b" agenda.txt`
    echo $DNIx
    menu
}
```

Comment: esto fallará si un nombre contiene un valor como el del DNI. Por ejemplo, si buscar DNI = 2 devolverá líneas con valor "45:Juan 2". Mejor Awk, mira mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

No puedo reproducir tu error. Dicho lo cual, probablemente deberías crear una condición más compleja para revisar los datos. Por ejemplo:

Para ver el DNI, valida que está al principio de la línea y le sigue el carácter ":":

```
grep "^$dni:" agenda.txt
```

Para ver el nombre, valida que está después de ":" y seguido por el final de la línea:

```
grep ":$nombre$" agenda.txt
```

---

Sin embargo, con Awk todo esto es mucho más fácil: tienes un fichero con campos separados por ":". Entonces, con Awk encontrar la fila cuya 2.ª columna es exactamente "Pepe" es tan fácil como decir:

```
awk -F: '$2=="Pepe"' fichero
```

Y lo mismo con la 1.ª columna:

```
awk -F: '$1==2' fichero
```

De esta forma, estarás encontrando exactamente lo que buscas, sin tener que recurrir a expresiones regulares ni retorcer Grep para que te filtre bien.

Así pues tu función quedaría en algo así como:

```
function buscarDNI ()
{
    echo "Introduce DNI a buscar:"
    read dni
    awk -F: -v valor_dni="$dni" '$1==valor_dni' fichero
    menu
}
```